# ListView getCheckedItemCount and getCheckPositions.size

Tags: android, android-listview, spinner, android-spinner, onclicklistener

I am receiving a weird ass bug and I can't seem to figure out why.  I have a "save" button and a drop down spinner with two options {select1 and select2}.  When the user press a button, the list view should save the the state of the check boxes.  If the user changes to either "select1" or "select2", the checks that were saved should be restored.

The problem is, for example under "select1", when I deselect a checkbox (so 2 out of 3) and save (using a button),  the two functions give me two different results.

```
ListView lv;
**Log.w(TAG,"saveResourceSettings. count: "+lv.getCheckedItemCount());**  <--- "count: 2"
SparseBooleanArray checked =lv.getCheckedItemPositions();

**Log.w(TAG,"saveResourceSettings. checked count: "+checked.size());** <----"checked count: 3" **?????????**
```

Does anyone know what is wrong? It is as if the SparseBooleanArray is not being updated when I deselect a checkbox. For example, if I deselect "com.android.gesture.builder" it still shows up in the array.

[image]

BTW, I'm using a custom data structure to save the state of the check boxes, which is working fine.

Just to make sure you know the context and methods, ill post part of the code:

```
packageListView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.ListView01);

packageListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice,appNames ));

packageListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);




spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.my_spinner);

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.s_p_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                       String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

                       ListView temp=null;

                       if(selected.equalsIgnoreCase("select1")){

                             temp= Utils.restoreChecks(packageListView,profile , resource,thisActivity, State.SELECT1);

                        }

                        else if(selected.equalsIgnoreCase("select2")){

                             temp= Utils.restoreChecks(packageListView,profile , resource,thisActivity, State.SELECT2);

                         }



                        packageListView=temp;

                        Log.w(TAG,"REFRESHING");

                      //packageListView.invalidate();

                      ArrayAdapter adapt= (ArrayAdapter) packageListView.getAdapter();

                     adapt.notifyDataSetChanged();


                   }

           });





Button save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);

save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


             public void onClick(View v) {



                        String spinnerSelected =spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

                        if(spinnerSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("select1")){

                                Log.w(TAG,"onCreate. count: "+packageListView.getCheckedItemCount());


                             AccessFileCmds.saveResourceSettings( packageListView, installedPackageNames, profile, resource,thisActivity, State.SELECT1);

                        }

                        else if(spinnerSelected.equalsIgnoreCase("select2")){

                              Log.w(TAG,"onCreate. count: "+packageListView.getCheckedItemCount());

                             AccessFileCmds.saveResourceSettings( packageListView, installedPackageNames, profile, resource,thisActivity, State.SELECT2);

                        }

         }

});
```

SOLUTION:

```
public static int[] getItemPositions(ListView lv){
    List<Integer> indexes=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();
    if (checkedItems != null) {
        for (int i=0; i<checkedItems.size(); i++) {
            if (checkedItems.valueAt(i)) {
                String item = lv.getAdapter().getItem(checkedItems.keyAt(i)).toString();
                Log.i(TAG,item + " was selected. index: "+checkedItems.keyAt(i));
                indexes.add(checkedItems.keyAt(i));
            }
        }
    }
    int[] ret=new int[indexes.size()];

    for(int i=0;i<indexes.size();i++){
        ret[i]=indexes.get(i);
    }
    return ret;
}
```